# SceneKit - Rotating around a point causing strange rotation

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, scenekit

I want to be able to rotate a camera around a cube (a collection of cubes), but for some reason, when I rotate, the rotation goes in multiple directions.

I have an object that I wish to rotate around and set this as a look at constraint. This object is in the middle of the cubes.

I have a swipe gesture recogniser that does the rotation...but it's just off. I'm missing something...

[image: Example Result]
[image: Example Result 2]

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit
import AVFoundation

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var scene:SCNScene!
    var tiles:[SCNNode] = [SCNNode]()
    var cameraNode:SCNNode!
    var centerNode:SCNNode!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create a new scene
        scene = SCNScene()

        let sideMaterial  = SCNMaterial()
        sideMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.greenColor()
        sideMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true;

        let geom = SCNBox(width: 32, height: 32.0, length: 32, chamferRadius: 8.0)
        geom.widthSegmentCount = 16
        geom.heightSegmentCount = 16
        geom.lengthSegmentCount = 16
        geom.materials = [sideMaterial, sideMaterial, sideMaterial, sideMaterial, sideMaterial, sideMaterial]


        centerNode = SCNNode(geometry: geom)
        centerNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 4*32, y: -4*32, z: -4*32)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(centerNode)

        // create and add a camera to the scene
        cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // place the camera

        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: -4*32, y: -4*32, z: 4*32)
        cameraNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(4*32, -4*32, -4*32)
        cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1.360646)

        let lookAt = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: centerNode)
        //lookAt.gimbalLockEnabled = true
        cameraNode.constraints = [lookAt]


        cameraNode.camera?.xFov = 90
        cameraNode.camera?.yFov = 90
        cameraNode.camera?.zNear = 1
        cameraNode.camera?.zFar = 5000

        // create and add a light to the scene
        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 4*32, y: -4*32, z: 10)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

        // create and add an ambient light to the scene
        let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
        ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
        ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
        ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)


        // retrieve the SCNView
        let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

        setupTiles()

        // set the scene to the view
        scnView.scene = scene

        // allows the user to manipulate the camera
        //scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

        // show statistics such as fps and timing information
        scnView.showsStatistics = true

        // configure the view
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        // Add gestures

        var gestureRecognizers = [UIGestureRecognizer]()

        let swipeDownGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipe:")
        swipeDownGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
        gestureRecognizers.append(swipeDownGesture)

        let swipeUpGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipe:")
        swipeUpGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
        gestureRecognizers.append(swipeUpGesture)

        let swipeLeftGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipe:")
        swipeLeftGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        gestureRecognizers.append(swipeLeftGesture)

        let swipeRightGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipe:")
        swipeRightGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        gestureRecognizers.append(swipeRightGesture)

        if let existingGestureRecognizers = scnView.gestureRecognizers as? [UIGestureRecognizer] {
            gestureRecognizers.extend(existingGestureRecognizers)
        }
        scnView.gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers
    }

    func swipe(gestureRecognize: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        var leftRight:Float = 0
        var upDown:Float = 0
        var amount:Float = 1.5707
        switch gestureRecognize.direction
        {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up:
            upDown = 1
            break
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down:
            upDown = -1
            break
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left:
            leftRight = -1
            break
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
            leftRight = 1
            break
        default:
            break
        }

        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(3.0)

        cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4(x: leftRight, y: upDown, z: 0, w: amount)

        SCNTransaction.commit()


    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

//    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
//        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
//            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown
//        } else {
//            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
//        }
//    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    func setupTiles()
    {


        for z in 0...7
        {
            for y in 0...7
            {
                for x in 0...7
                {

                    if y > 0 && y < 7 && z > 0 && z < 7 && x > 0 && x < 7
                    {
                        continue
                    }

                    let topMaterial = SCNMaterial()
                    topMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.whiteColor()
                    topMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true;

                    let sideMaterial  = SCNMaterial()
                    sideMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.whiteColor()
                    sideMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true;

                    let geom = SCNBox(width: 32, height: 32.0, length: 32, chamferRadius: 8.0)
                    geom.widthSegmentCount = 16
                    geom.heightSegmentCount = 16
                    geom.lengthSegmentCount = 16
                    geom.materials = [topMaterial, sideMaterial, sideMaterial, sideMaterial, sideMaterial, sideMaterial]


                    let node = SCNNode(geometry: geom)
                    node.position = SCNVector3(x: Float(x) * 32.0, y: -(Float(y) * 32.0), z: -(Float(z) * 32.0))

                    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

                    tiles.append(node)

                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Edit:

Setting the transform instead of the rotation seems to have better effects

```
    centerNode = SCNNode(geometry: geom)
    centerNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Identity
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(centerNode)

    // create and add a camera to the scene
    cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    // place the camera

    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 8*32)
    cameraNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, -8*32)

    let lookAt = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: centerNode)
    lookAt.gimbalLockEnabled = true
    cameraNode.constraints = [lookAt]

    cameraNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Identity

    //In gesture
    cameraNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(cameraNode.transform, amount, upDown, leftRight, 0)
```